# Why can 'hallo\nworld' match both \n and \\n in R?

Tags: regex, r, escaping

Why does `grep` treat `\n`  and  `\\n` the same way ?

For example, both match `hallo\nworld`.

```
grep("hallo\nworld", pattern="\n")
[1] 1
grep("hallo\nworld", pattern="\\n")
[1] 1
```

I see that `hallo\nworld` is parsed into

```
hallo  
world
```

that is, `hallo` on one line and `world` on one line.

So in `grep("hallo\nworld", pattern="\n")`, is the `pattern="\n"` a new line or `\n` literally?

Also note this happens with others; `\a` `\f` `\n` `\t` `\r` and `\\a` `\\f` `\\n` `\\t` `\\r` are all treated identically.  But `\d` `\w` `\s` can't be used!  Why not?

I chose different strings to test, and I found the secret in the concept of regular expression.

There are two concepts of escape, one is escape in a string, it is simple to understand; the other is escape in a regular pattern expression string.  In R a pattern such as `grep(x, pattern=" some string here ")`,  `\\n`=`\n`= a newline character. But in common string, `\\n` !=`\n` ,the former is literally `\n`,the latter is a newline character. We can prove this by :

```
cat("\n")

cat("\\n")
\n>
```

How to prove this? I'll try with other characters, not just `\n`, to see if they match in the same way.

```
special1 <- c( "\a", "\f", "\n", "\t", "\r")
special2 <- c("\\a","\\f","\\n","\\t","\\r")
target <- paste("hallo", special1, "world", sep="")
for (i in 1:5){
    cat("i=", i, "\n")
    if( grep(target[i], pattern=special1[i]) == 1)
        print(paste(target[i], "match", special1[i], "succeed"))
    if( grep(target[i], pattern=special2[i]) == 1)
        print(paste(target[i], "match", special2[i], "succeed"))
}
```

output:

```
i= 1   
[1] "hallo\aworld match \a succeed"  
[1] "hallo\aworld match `\\a` succeed"  
i= 2   
[1] "hallo\fworld match \f succeed"  
[1] "hallo\fworld match `\\f` succeed"  
i= 3   
[1] "hallo\nworld match \n succeed"  
[1] "hallo\nworld match `\\n` succeed"  
i= 4   
[1] "hallo\tworld match \t succeed"  
[1] "hallo\tworld match `\\t` succeed"  
i= 5   
[1] "hallo\rworld match \r succeed"  
[1] "hallo\rworld match `\\r` succeed"
```

Note that `\a` `\f` `\n` `\t` `\r` and  `\\a` `\\f` `\\n` `\\t` `\\r`  were all treated identically in R regular pattern expression string!

Not only that, you can not write `\d` `\w` `\s` in an R regular expression pattern!
You can write any of these:

```
pattern="\a" "pattern=\f" "pattern=\n" "pattern=\t" "pattern=\r"
```

But you can't write any of these!

```
pattern="\d" "pattern="\w" "pattern=\s"  in grep.
```

I think this is also a bug , as `\d` `\w` `\s` are treated unequally to `\a` `\f` `\n` `\t` `\r`.

Comment: Actually, it's the other way round: Both `\n` and `\\n` match `"hallo\nworld"`, or, to be more precise, a substring of `"hallo\nworld"`. Also, please be more precise with your question: What do you want to achieve? Why do you care about the difference? Is there an application where `pattern` is user input? In short, more detail please! (Also, putting a space *before* the comma and none *after* it really bites the eye. It's really "word" "comma" "space" "word".)

Comment: Why don't you write your last edit as answer?

Comment: If you are convinced this is a bug, then you should write to [R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel) about it. Relatively few R Core members are on SO, so they are unlikely to see it here.

Comment: As far as `\d`, `\w` and `\s` are concerned, the difference from `\a`, `\f`, `\n`, `\t` and `\r` is that they are character classes, not characters. Character escape sequences have their meaning in any string while character classes don’t.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why `\n`, `\\n` and `\\\n` all match is because of *double evaluation* of the search pattern. I observed this by running a couple of examples:

```
grep("hello\nworld", pattern="\n")
[1] 1
grep("hello\nworld", pattern="\\n")
[1] 1
> grep("hello\nworld", pattern="\\\n")
[1] 1
> grep("hello\nworld", pattern="\\\\n")
integer(0)
> grep("hello\\nworld", pattern="\\\\n")
[1] 1
```

Keep in mind the rules of evaluating backslash escape sequences:

- `\\` is replaced with a `\`
- `\n` is replaced with a `NEWLINE` character
- `\` + `NEWLINE` is replaced with a `NEWLINE` character
- (see the docs in `?regex` for more details)

With this in mind, if you evaluate the pattern *twice*, you get:

1. `\n` => `NEWLINE` => `NEWLINE`
2. `\\n` => `\n` => `NEWLINE`
3. `\\\n` => `\` + `NEWLINE` => `NEWLINE`
4. `\\\\n` => `\\n` => `\n`
5. `\\\\\n` => `\\` + `NEWLINE` => `\` + `NEWLINE`
6. `\\\\\\n` => `\\\n` => `\` + `NEWLINE`
7. `\\\\\\\n` => `\\\` + `NEWLINE` => `\` + `NEWLINE`
8. `\\\\\\\\n` => `\\\\n` => `\\n`

And so on. Examples 1-3 all evaluate to a single `NEWLINE`, that's why these patterns will match. (At the same time, the string you're trying to match against the pattern is evaluated only once.)

[A discussion on the R mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-August/037524.html) posted by [@Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210673/aaron) explains the double evaluation like this:

> There are two levels [of evaluation] because backslashes are escape characters both to
>   R strings and regular expressions.

Note that other languages don't evaluate patterns like this. Take for example Python:

```
import re
>>> re.search(r'\n', 'hello\nworld') is not None
True
>>> re.search(r'\\n', 'hello\nworld') is not None
False
```

Or Perl:

```
$ perl -e 'print "hello\nworld" =~ /\n/ || 0, "\n"'
1
$ perl -e 'print "hello\nworld" =~ /\\n/ || 0, "\n"'
0
```

And we could go on. So the double evaluation in `R` seems unusual. Why is it implemented this way? I think the ultimate answer lies with [R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel).

**ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS**

I thank [@Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210673/aaron) whose critical comments helped improving this answer.

Comment: This sounds good, but I'm pretty sure both `"\\n"` and `"\n"` are already character strings, so calling `as.character` on them has no effect.

Comment: Yes, your last sentence exactly. See my answer.

Comment: R is evaluating backslashes (not patterns) twice because backslashes are need to be escaped both in the R string and in the regular expression.  See my answer.

Comment: Also, I suggest editing your answer to put the actual answer first and remove the wrong portions.

Comment: Much better, thanks.  Though I don't think the `Internal` stuff matters, and so in my opinion distracts from the answer.

Comment: R does it like this because it doesn't have a special quoting format for regular expressions like python and perl do. In python, try `re.search('\n', 'hello\nworld')` and `re.search('\\n', 'hello\nworld')`

Answer (score 4):

**Note** that the backslash itself is special, you have to escape the backslash with a backslash.

The `\\n` means "I really want to match a newline character, not literal `\n`"

```
grep("hallo\nworld", pattern = "\\n")
[1] 1

grep("hallo\\nworld", pattern = "\\\\n")
[1] 1
```

Comment: Or use the `fixed = TRUE` argument... `grep("hallo\\nworld", pattern = "\\n" , fixed = TRUE )`

Comment: if `\\n` is parsed a newline character,`\n` was parsed literal `\n`, the `\n` in `hallo\nworld` was parsed a newline character or  literal `\n`?according the facts that `hallo\nworld` matched both `\n` and `\\n` ,there is a bug in R regular expression and grep function,it is a logical contradiction .

Comment: Yes, I assume it's a possible bug.

Answer (score 4):

Following up hwnd's answer, take a look at the following:

```
cat("x\ny")
## x
## y
cat("x\\ny")
## x\ny
grep("hallo\nworld", pattern="[\n]")
## [1] 1
grep("hallo\nworld", pattern="[\\n]")
## integer(0)
```

So: `"\n"` is literal newline, `"\\n"` is backslash + `n`, which is interpreted by `grep` as a newline. That's why in my first example a match is found (searching for any character in the set `{ newline }`), and in my second example no match is found (searching for any character in the set `{ \ n }`).

It's not a bug, it's perfectly expected behavior. On that note, to be *really* and *absolutely* sure, why don't you [post](http://www.r-project.org/mail.html) to R-help or R-devel?

Comment: no sir ,it is a problem, pattern="[\\n]"  is  `\+n` two characters ,so `grep("hallo\nworld", pattern="[\\n]")` can not match.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: Yes, that's what we see and that's what I would expect, and also that's what I wrote. Sorry if my explanation is not clear enough.

Comment: there is no doubt that `hallo\nworld` can match one of them: `\n` and `\\n`.  there is mcuh doubt that why `hallo\nworld` can match both of them: `\n` and `\\n`.  hwnd  think maybe it is a bug ,i think too,you don't think so ,please answer the problem directly ,why can match both of them, you explain why it can match one of them and the reason,how about the another case?

Comment: +1 Yes, this.  I didn't see it right away, though, because the bracket example confused me.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed due to the "double escaping" mentioned by lebatsnok.  As Peter Dalgaard wrote on R-help, "backslashes are escape characters both to  R strings and regular expressions." See https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-August/037524.html.  Also see the note on doubling backslashes in `?regex`, though to me that's not as clear as Dalgaard's comment.

So `\n` becomes a newline character in the first pass, and stays that way in the second.

`\\n` becomes `\n` in the first pass (`\\`->`\`), and then becomes a newline in the second.

`\\\n` becomes `\` followed by a newline in the first pass, which apparently becomes just a newline in the second pass, as it matches as well.

Also, about the issue with a, f, n, t, and r allowed to have backslashes but d, w, and s are not, note that those are specific metacharacters with special meaning, as noted in `?regex`:

> The current implementation interprets
>        '\a' as 'BEL', '\e' as 'ESC', '\f' as 'FF', '\n' as 'LF', '\r' as
>        'CR' and '\t' as 'TAB'.

Comment: On rereading @krlmlr's answer, I note that this is exactly what is said there; I was perhaps confused by the example with brackets.

Comment: `\\\n` becomes a newline, because an escaped newline is a newline, naturally, just like an escaped space is a space, and so on. The `?regex` help explains which escape sequences have a special meaning, like `\t` is a tab, and everything not listed there is evaluated to itself, hence `\NEWLINE -> NEWLINE`

Answer (score -1):

Because the string `hallo\nworld` contains the literal text `\n` as well as a `line feed` character when it is parsed.

If your string was actually:

```
hallo
world
```

It would then match only `\n` and not `\\n`.

Comment: wrong. when you start new line in the middle of the string, this means "\n" (i.e newline character)

Comment: Compare this: https://www.debuggex.com/r/bIizu2GWMX4dop00 .... with this: https://www.debuggex.com/r/0pQDL9dvfNOuHn-k .... and this: https://www.debuggex.com/r/vI3jjORfA7AAW0-k .

Comment: Like I said... it contains it as a literal string, and it is a LF character when parsed. Easy to understand, and not incorrect.

Comment: Try `source("http://www.psych.ee/ajutine/easy.R", echo=TRUE)`. If it were as you said, the result should be FALSE instead of what it's now.

Comment: That's fantastic - still doesn't explain why the string matches both `\n` and `\\n`.

Comment: Of course not. I don't pretend to have an answer (looks like a bug at first sight but maybe have something to do with the "double escaping" in R which I've never understood and have used only by trial-and-error) - just wanted to point out that your explanation isn't really correct (it may be correct for some other language though).